# Running code when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have this link that fills an input when clicked.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('input').value='<?php echo("$ms"); ?>'">
```

I was wondering how I would get it to do this automatically onload.

Comment: Are you willing to use a library like jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$ms` has been made safe for XSS:

```
<input value="<?php echo $ms; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually put it in onload, don't know if there is a best practise:

```
<body onload="myFunc()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onload` property of an element :

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('input').value='<?php echo("$ms"); ?>'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [onLoad event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) to the `<body>` element of your document:

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('input').value='<?php echo("$ms"); ?>'">
```

Furthermore, it looks like you are using PHP, if you just want to use `$ms` to set the value of `#input` you could also use something like:

```
<?php
echo '<input type="text" id="input" value="'.$ms.'"/>
?>
```